# Rails + Devise + Facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an API and a Web app working with Rails and Devise gem for authentication.
With Devise and Omniauth I can make the Signup with facebook and Login with Facebook through the web site. 
I have my API protected with token_authenticable and a TokensController, so when you want to interact with my API first you have to pass to the TokensController your username and password and it will give you a valid token, my problem is what happen when the user is sign up with facebook, Shall I pass to the TokensController the username and the facebook token to generate the token? are there some standard way to do this?

Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments; After thinking which one would be the best option, Here is what I finally did:

Note: I separate the code in client and server side(API)

**Client Side**:

- Get the Facebook token and the Facebook user ID for a certain user.
- Call the API method *Create* method from *TokensController*, with the parameters I got above.

**Server side**:

- I receive the Facebook token and the Facebook User ID.
- Using the Facebook Token I get the Facebook User ID from the API.
- I validate that the receive UID from the request and the Facebook UID are the same.
- If the UID are the same I generate a random token for my app and I return it in the response.

Note: All the communication is done via HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can pick whatever you want, as long as it fits your criteria:

- it's secret
- it's retrievable for you
- it has a minimum security (not just '123pw')

So you have two similar options:

- Use the Facebook Token as 'password'
- Use the password generated by Devise

Normally you generate a password when creating a Facebook user with Devise. I guess you have code like `:password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]` in your `User.create`-call?

The encrypted password is normally 60 characters, the Facebook token can have [up to 255 characters](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/572/). So I personally would pick the Devise generated password. It's long enough to be safe and you don't depend on an API to retrieve it.